# Logstash duplicates template properties

Tags: templates, elasticsearch, logstash

I'm trying to set a custom template for a specific index. The issue is when I create it in Kibana, I see some duplicated properties such as `type` and `_type` (with the "_"). I've been trying different template "approaches" but without success... Also, I guess the default template keeps overriding the custom one.

This is my output configuration:

```
output {
  if [type] == "something" {
    elasticsearch {
      (... omitted ...)
      manage_template => true
      index => "log-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
      template_name => "log-template"
      template => "/etc/logstash/templates.d/log.json"
      template_overwrite => true
    }
  }
```

The following is my template file:

```
{
  "template": "log-*",
  "order": 1,
  "settings": { "index.refresh_interval": "5s" },
  "mappings":
  {
    "_default_":
      {
        "dynamic": "strict",
        "_all": { "enabled": false },
        "properties":
        {
          "@timestamp": { "type": "date", "format": "dateOptionalTime" },
          "file": { "type": "string" },
          "host": { "type": "string" },
          "host": { "type": "string" }
        }
      }
  }
}
```

Before I try each new template config I stop logstash, remove all the indexes and templates - just like the official documentation suggests. Only after, I run run logstash and create the index at Kibana.

Comment: `type` is the type field you're probably creating within your logstash input config and referencing in your output as `"something"` and `_type` is the name of the mapping type of the document created by logstash.

Comment: Yes, I known that. But it is not pretty to have that in Kibana :) Any way to only display `type`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you go to Settings > Advanced, you can edit the `metaFields` setting and only write `_source` in there, so that `_type`, `_id` and `_index` don't show up anymore:

[image]

Then reload your Kibana page and in the Discover tab you'll only see the `_source` field.

Comment: the underscore fields keep showing in the Discovery

Comment: have you saved the setting and reloaded the page? What does your `metaFields` setting say now?

Comment: yes, I did. `metaFields` only shows `_source`. The underscore fields disappear after their creation in Kibana. However, when I click "Discover" they are there.

Comment: Nevermind. I've just figured it out. I have to apply the `metaFields` over an existing index. I removed the index 1st and created it again, thinking it would be the right way. Thanks @Val

Comment: the underscore fields are back the next day. Any way to make this permanent?